# How to apply color gradient in progress bar in high chart with stylemode in Angular

Tags: angular, highcharts, progress-bar

I am looking for the solution where I can apply the gradient color to the progress bar based on the data I am getting but the thing here is I have used `styleMode:true` here now I have try clreating classes but creating dynamic css classes and appending it here with the object is not seemed possible so looking for the possible solution where I get to apply gradient color schemes to the progress bar

[image]

earlier in code I have been using something like this :

```
currentObj.color = this.highchartUtil.getColorPerLegend(duration,isDelay);

//function
getColorPerLegend(pertPoint){
  let colorObject = {
    linearGradient:{x:0,x2:1,y:0},
    stops:[]
  };
    colorObject.stops=[[pertPoint,green],
    [pertPoint,orange],
    [1,orange]];
    return colorObject;

  }
}
```

this code was working fine before `styleMode` was disabled. Now since I had to enable it due to some reason I am looking for the possible solution to apply gradient color. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the fill of this bar in the CSS in the **.highcharts-partfill-overlay**.

```
.highcharts-partfill-overlay {
  fill: red;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n75coyu8/

Let know if this solution suits you.